# /boot/messages in SuSE?

Tags: boot, system-installation, suse

I'm reading a SUSE Linux tutorial for creating a **custom installation CD** from host's kernel.

As first step it indicates to create a `iso/boot/grub` folder system and perform the files copying indicated below:

```
cp /boot/vmlinuz boot/
cp /boot/initrd boot/
cp /boot/message boot/
cp /usr/lib/grub/stage2_eltorito boot/grub
cp /boot/grub/menu.lst boot/grub
```

So, for **`stage2_eltorito`**, it must be copied from **`/usr/share/grub/x86_64-redhat`**. But what about **`/boot/message`**? I used `locate` but got not results.

And, what is this needed for so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/boot/message` is just the message displayed when the boot manager is loaded. It could be anything you like, just a simple text file with a greeting:

> Have a lot of fun!

Or something like that. You should be able to ignore it quite safely. You could also create it yourself. The easiest thing would be to just run

```
sudo touch /boot/message
```

Comment: This is about GRUB, not lilo :)

Comment: @Diego yes, grub can use `/boot/message` as well, you're right. In any case it is just the greeting message, don't worry about it. It is not necessary, I don't have one for example. Just create an empty file if it makes you feel better but it is not needed.